# How to handle CRUD operation with Diffable Data Source & NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

I have a simple product store screen of 4 rows with each row containing 4-5 products.

Currently I have the following setup

- Controller calls the backend server and gets the data
- Save the models to Core Data
- This triggers an update of NSFetchedResultsController
- Apply the new snapshot using Diffable Data Source

This setup works great when new products are added to any row or are updated in some way.

But I am unable to find a way on how to handle the scenario when a product is removed in the API response ? because whenever I receive a response I save it in Core Data base and then rely on the FRC trigger to apply the snapshot.

So If an existing product is removed in the response the product still continues to show in the store as it also needs to be removed in the DB as well. So before saving into DB I always have to delete all the existing data and then save the new data for changes to take effect.

Can anybody suggest a change in my setup to handle this scenario or any particular flow to handle it ?

Comment: Can't you just remove the deleted item from Core Data?

Comment: @Paulw11 how will I be able to keep track of that ?... If I take this approach then I have to fetch all data from DB check for any deletions, delete it and then save the new data..... is this the correct way or is there any easy method ?

Comment: Keeping an on-device cache of remote data is non-trivial. If you want to do it your server really needs to keep a transaction log database; that way your app can fetch the transactions since the last time it updated.  This log database will contain the identifiers of records that have been inserted and deleted that can be used to update the local database.  If you don't have a transaction log then you either need to fetch the full database each time or don't use a local cache; fetch records from the network as required and keep them only in memory.

Comment: One other approach is to provide an API endpoint that accepts a list of record ids and returns the record ids that are no longer valid; This way you can more efficiently determine which records have been deleted without needing to transfer entire records.

Comment: The second approach seems efficient for what I want to achieve but as of now I don't have the expertise to implement that,  the only reason to save the API response to DB was to maintain a local cache in event where internet was not there and user viewed the product screen

Comment: If not Core Data what form of persistence you suggest for non trivial data ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228780/discussion-between-paulw11-and-nikhil-muskur).